# Weak convergence everywhere implied by weak convergence in Sobolev-Bochner-Space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

I want to understand an implication made by M. Sofonea and A. Matei in their book "Variational Inequalities with Applications". The sequence $\lbrace u_n \rbrace_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be bounded in $L^\infty(0,T;X)$ and $\lbrace u_n'\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be bounded in $L^2(0,T;X)$. Then we can extract a subsequence with

\begin{align*}
u_n &\rightharpoonup^* u \text{ in } L^\infty(0,T;X) \\
u_n' &\rightharpoonup u' \text{ in } L^2(0,T;X).
\end{align*}

Well, then the say, that

\begin{align*}
u_n(t) \rightharpoonup u(t)
\end{align*}

for all $t\in[0,T]$. Can someone give me a quote or a proof, why this holds? Thanks, FFoDWindow